# Access Loop Thru Columns to update records

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an Access table with about 20 columns, each column with a unique name, but all columns that I want to update start with TT.  The columns have only 1 word in them "applied", but not all records are populated.  I want to run some summary reports on this data, but want to change the word "applied" to the number "1".  My problem is that the column names change, a new column could be added or removed at any time, so I don't want to hard code the column names in a sql statement.

What is the best way to cycle thru all of the columns and update the records in each column without defining each column by a static name?  I need to keep the original record as "applied", but also be able to use the number 1 in it's place as needed.

There are about 6mil records in the table.

Answer (score 1):

You can't updated fields or (Columns), you can only update records (or Rows).  However, you CAN figure out which fields fit your description.  I don't really understand the question, but maybe you can add the field names to an array, then strip the array out and only update the fields that start with "TT".  The code to find your field names is as follows:

```
Function TableInfo(strTableName As String)
On Error GoTo TableInfoErr
   ' Purpose:   Display the field names, types, sizes and descriptions for a table.
   ' Argument:  Name of a table in the current database.
   Dim db As DAO.Database
   Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
   Dim fld As DAO.Field
   Dim StrSQL As String

   Set db = CurrentDb()
   Set tdf = db.TableDefs(strTableName)

   For Each fld In tdf.Fields
      If Left(fld.name, 2) = "TT" then
         'Your field name starts with TT.  Do some processing...
         StrSQL = "UPDATE " & strTableName & " SET " & fld.Name & " = 1 WHERE " & fld.Name & " = 'Applied'"
         DoCmd.Execute StrSQL
      End If   
   Next


TableInfoExit:
   Set db = Nothing
   Exit Function

TableInfoErr:
   Select Case Err
   Case 3265&  'Table name invalid
      MsgBox strTableName & " table doesn't exist"
   Case Else
      Debug.Print "TableInfo() Error " & Err & ": " & Error
   End Select
   Resume TableInfoExit
End Function
```

Comment: Let me see if I can better explain.  I want to run a query against a table with dynamic column names and update the fields in the table based on the column name.  For instance:

Column:
NAME USER TT1       TT2      TT3      TT4
USR1 ABC  APPLIED   APPLIED
USR2 CDE            APPLIED           APPLIED
USR3 DQE                     APPLIED

I want to create a query that will cycle thru all of the fields that start with TT and update the word "APPLIED" to the number "1".  My challenge is that next month I may have different column names, with the same criteria "APPLIED" = "1".

Comment: Any query with dynamic column names is going to need to be dynamically created.  There's absolutely no way around that.  I'll see if I can tweak the code in my answer, but you're going to have to take what I'm writing and go over the goal line with it.  I can't give you 100% of the answer because I don't know 100% of the problem, only what you're telling me.  I'll edit the code in about 5 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this.  What I was thinking is possibly creating a table that captures the column names and then using the names from the ad-hoc table as a column reference.  does that seem feasible?

Comment: I pasted your code in module1, I had to change the docmd.execute StrSQL to docmd.runsql StrSQL, that seemed to work, but when I added the function call to the onclick procedure of a button to test it, I added TableInfo (testable)  and I receive the error table doesn't exist.  Did I miss something?  I do have a table called testable...

Comment: Use `db.Execute StrSQL, dbFailonerror` and enclose your table name in quotes when you call the function: `TableInfo("testable")`

Comment: @HansUP I made the changes, while I do not get the table error any more, my columns do not update to the number 1 from Applied.

Comment: Add this line before `db.Execute`: `Debug.Print StrSQL` Then run your code, go to the Immediate window (Ctrl+g) and copy the text of one of those `UPDATE` statements.  Create a new query in the query designer, switch to SQL View, and paste in the text you copied.  What happens when you try to run that query from the query designer?

Comment: @HansUp - I found the problem, with your assistance.  The field names have spaces in them, so that was probably the problem.  Once I removed the spaces it worked like a champ.